# what is the best way to post array in ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, post

I have an java script array created as -

```
var ar = new Array();
ar[0] = 'foo';
ar[1] = 'bar';
```

I need to know what is best way to post it to server using ajax (jquery)? Do i need to serialize it before post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send it as it is,

```
var ar = ..your_array..;
$.ajax({
     url: 'http://www.example.com/',
     data: {array: ar},
     type: 'POST'
});
```

You can also use jquery $.post and $.get function.

Answer (score 0):

may be this is the best way .

```
var data  = {fookey:"foo",barkey:"bar"};
```

and in your ajax code

```
$.ajax(function(){
.....
data:data
sucess:...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to send the array to the server, a JSON style string would probably work best. If I recall correctly, you can use `JSON.stringify(ar);`, but that isn't cross browser compatible. In this case, it would probably be easier to write the string yourself.

```
var json_string = '{0:foo, 1:bar}';
```

You can then decode it server side with `json_decode()` in PHP. I'm assuming you're using PHP, because your initial question is somewhat vague.

For the actual AJAX request code, you can look that up yourself. Sorry. :P